# calculating geospatial indexes for h3 at any given resolution

Tags: node.js, h3

I am just starting out with Uber's h3geo (JavaScript), and am getting half the number of indexes at every resolution than [what the docs suggest](https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/restable).

```js
const nw = [-180,  90];
const ne = [ 180,  90];
const se = [ 180, -90];
const sw = [-180, -90];
let rect = [nw, ne, se, sw];
const res = 0;
const grid = h3.polyfill(rect, res);
console.log(grid.length);
// res 0 output → 61, should output 122
// res 1 output → 421, should 842
// res 2 output → 2951, should 5882
// res 3 output → 20580; should output 41162
// and so on
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally, the `h3geo` [docs for regions](https://h3geo.org/docs/api/regions) show `lat` first and `lng` second. As shown above, I am using `[lng, lat]`. If I flip them, I consistently get `grid.length` as 0. And if I give a geoJson, I get an error saying `coordinates don't have a length property`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered in part [here](https://github.com/uber/geojson2h3/issues/25), but responding here as well for visibility:

- `h3.polyfill` expects `[lat, lng]` pairs, unless you pass `true` for the third `isGeoJson` argument. So you are currently polyfilling the reverse coordinates, which is why you get the wrong number of cells.
- The H3 polyfill function only works at present with shapes with width < 180 degrees of longitude. We ignore winding order and use the smaller shape where possible. If you divide the bounding box into two shapes, you should get expected results. This is why you get no results for the `[lat, lng]` input.
- `h3-js` doesn't support full GeoJSON input, you need `geojson2h3` to handle GeoJSON structures.

This is admittedly a documentation issue for H3, which we'll try to update.

Comment: thanks @nrabinowitz. First, thanks to you and Uber for making (and making available) `h3geo`. It is really wonderful, very well thought through. It has a few documentation glitches. I was confused on several occasions so I know the docs could be clearer. That said, I look forward to getting a lot of use out of h3 and doing fun things with it.